# MySQL Calculate rank then update table from a result

Tags: mysql, rank

My issue is I am trying to calculate all user entries and then rank them. After I rank them I want to update the users table to record each user's rank.

Tables:

userTbl

activityTbl

I have search all night and this is what I have so far.

```
SET @rank := 0;
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank, a.userName
FROM activityTbl a
LEFT JOIN userTbl u ON a.userName = u.userName
GROUP BY a.userName
ORDER BY SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( a.actTime ) )DESC
) as sub
```

This returns:

rank|user

1 Kim

2        John

3        Joe

This is fine, but I've tried to add Update and Set to this query to update the userTbl and I just can't get it to work.

Please help! Let me know if you need more information.

UPDATE:

For those looking for exactly what I did to correct my problem.

First, I posted the wrong MySQL. The one I used to fix my problem is:

```
SET @rownum := 0;
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, userName, actTimeTotal 
FROM (SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(actTime)) AS actTimeTotal , userName 
FROM activityTbl 
GROUP BY userName 
ORDER BY actTimeTotal DESC) as result
```

Second, I created a rank table called rankTbl with 2 columns: rank smallInt and userName varchar.

Third, modified MySql script to:

```
SET @rownum := 0;
INSERT INTO rankTbl( rank, userName)
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, userName 
FROM (SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(actTime))AS actTimeTotal , userName 
FROM activityTbl 
GROUP BY userName 
ORDER BY actTimeTotal DESC) as result
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE userName = VALUES(userName);
```

I changed the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to userName instead of rank. When rank changed the rank did not update for the userName. Using userName update changes in rank.

Comment: can you provide your complete schema on sqlfiddle with your question clearified

Comment: what do the `userTbl` and `activityTbl` look like?

Comment: userTbl columns: userNum userName email rank activityTbl columns: actNum userName(FK) actName actDate actTime   I need to familiarize myself with sqlfiddle since I've never used it before. I'll try to get something up there ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is make sure that your ranking table has primary key on the user and then issue an INSERT of the SELECT with a KEY error provision:

Asuming your table is named `tbl` and contains a `rank` field and a `user` field, what I'm basically saying is that you need the following query to return a **duplicate key error** for all rows:

```
SET @rank := 0;
INSERT INTO tbl (rank, user)
    SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank, a.userName
    FROM activityTbl a
    LEFT JOIN userTbl u ON a.userName = u.userName
    GROUP BY a.userName
    ORDER BY SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(a.actTime)) DESC;
```

Once you have that and you are sure it returns a **duplicate key error** for all rows it is trying to insert, you modify it as follows:

```
SET @rank := 0;
INSERT INTO tbl (rank, user)
    SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank, a.userName
    FROM activityTbl a
    LEFT JOIN userTbl u ON a.userName = u.userName
    GROUP BY a.userName
    ORDER BY SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(a.actTime)) DESC
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rank = VALUES(rank);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I wasn't using a rank table before. I'll try this out and I'll let you know!

Comment: Thank you!!!!! It wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but you definitely pushed me in the right direction!!!!

Comment: you didn't need to create a separate table in the DB but it probably helped